# how to scale x axis to make data prettier

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

This is a scatter plot

My data's range is large.

Their x range is between 0.1 < x < 1 or 100< x<300.

It's very difficult to see the data,

How to change the x-axis scale, I want to change the x-axis scale as the RED text on the graph ?

In one word, I only want my x-axis shown in this way
(I want it nonlinear, every sample is linear, equi-distant each point)
[image]

[image]

### update

After I add the tickValues, it only mark those labels.

I expect it can be equal-distant among `[0, 0.1, 1,10, 150, 330]`

```
chart.xAxis
        .tickValues(function(d) {
        return [0, 0.1, 1,10, 150, 330];
      });
```

[image]

Comment: Could you put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so someone can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `xAxis.tickValues`, try the following :

```
// Tick values for the chart
chart.xAxis.tickValues(function(d) {
    var dateSets = [0, 0.1, 1,10, 150, 330];
    return dateSets;
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hi but it didn't scale it. only mark it, see my update thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You may probably use the log scale (d3.scale.log) to have the axis equally distributed amongst the broadly stretched values

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a log scale to address exponential growing data. See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5537697).